# Creating End Nodes using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing

Is there any way, other than Planarizing the lines, to create an end node automatically when snapping one line to the vertex of edge of another line.

Comment: When starting to use this site it is well worth taking its 2-minute [Tour] and reviewing [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question).  Our protocols are quite different to (and I think much better than) those of discussion forums and other Q&A sites.

Comment: A few years ago I got a tool from ArcScripts in C# that did just that, it may still be there but so are a lot of other tools. Beware of what you ask for because such a tool can have disastrous consequences if you make a simple mistake and don't catch it in time - which is why I don't still have the tool. If you've got a topology you can find the intersections quickly using the topology toolbar, provided you have set the rule 'must not intersect or touch interior' and 'must not self intersect'.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're wanting to split an existing line automatically when creating a new line that snaps to the edge or a vertex of an existing one? That seems like a better way to word the question. I'm not aware of one. We always planned for such junctions or had to use split line at point after creating the new one.

Comment: Chris W - Yes I have two massive vector datasets totally ~20 million features) which we are conflating and rather than Planarize the final conflated data set (which would , in our case, cause additional problems) we were wondering if there is a way of creating endnotes when one line is snapped to another.

Comment: I'm guessing the additional problem you refer to is creating junctions where there shouldn't be, like overpasses. I'm thinking there is a way to do this because it could be a required step for network creation, but I can't recall - I'll do some digging. As an alternative, would it work to just alter the connectivity policy to allow junctions at any vertex rather than just end nodes? Or is that yet another set of problems?

Comment: What if you use Feature Vertices to Point, restricting it to start/end nodes, and then use those points as input to Split Line at Point?

Comment: That is a potential idea - I'll look into that